# inputrc GNU readline vi-insert mode mappings do not seem to take effect

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, readline, inputrc, vi-mode

I have set vi-mode in my `~/.inputrc`. The command-mode keybinds seem to work fine whereas the insert-mode keybindings do not have any effect at all.

Specifically, the following are my insert mode mappings from my `~/.input`

```
# these are for vi-insert mode
set keymap vi-insert
"\e\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e\e[B": history-search-forward
Control-l: clear-screen
Control-p: previous-history
Control-n: next-history
# Two escapes clear command line. (Use C-c or \eC\eC instead)
"\e\e": "\e0\C-ki"
```

None of these mappings work in insert mode. I have the same mappings in command-mode and they all work fine.

As a concrete example, if I press `C-l` in the bash shell on `gnome-terminal`, it simply echoes `^L` on the screen, whereas in command mode, it correctly clears the screen. I do not understand why this is happening?

How can I fix this problem, and get insert-mode vi keybindings to work with the GNU readline library?